# R histogram number of instances in each bin on plot

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I would like to see the number of instances for each bin show up on the graph as well

```
set.seed(1)
x<-rnorm(1:100)
hist(x)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
set.seed(1)
x<-rnorm(1:100)
y <- hist(x, plot=FALSE)
plot(y, ylim=c(0, max(y$counts)+5))
text(y$mids, y$counts+3, y$counts, cex=0.75)
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another much simpler solution is just to use **labels=TRUE** in the **hist(...)** method itself. It will include number of occurrences/counts on the top of each bins in the histogram plot.

However, I would recommend to always include **xlim** and **ylim** for the histogram plots.

Code:

```
 set.seed(1)
 x <- rnorm(1:100)
 hist(x, xlim = c(-3,3), ylim = c(1,30), labels = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

that automatically happen. it's called "frequency" on the left

Comment: I would like the exact number of each number of occurrences not as a range on the y axis, but on the graph within each bin

Comment: yeah, Jilber's answer is perfect.